# MongoDB - $lte 2 keys against each other in the same object

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

Sample data:

```
let arrObj = [
  {
    "id": 9999,
    "arrObj": [
      {
        "name": "xyz",
        "arrId": 1,
        "total1": 54,
        "total2": 55
      },
      {
        "type": "abc",
        "arrId": 2,
         "total1": 35,
        "total2": 32
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Looking for mongo update like:

```
db.coll('collectionName').update({
  id: 9999,
  arrObj.arrId: 1,
  arrObj.total1 : {$lte : arrObj.total2}
},{$inc : {total2 : 1}})
```

I need to match 2 fields and based on it i need to increment one of the field value. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [update with aggregation pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/update-documents-with-aggregation-pipeline/) starting from MongoDB v4.2,

- `$map`, check your conditions if match found then add one to `total2`

```
db.coll('collectionName').update(
  { id: 9999 },
  [{
    $set: {
      arrObj: {
        $map: {
          input: "$arrObj",
          in: {
            $mergeObjects: [
              "$$this",
              {
                $cond: [
                  {
                    $and: [
                      { $eq: ["$$this.arrId", 1] },
                      { $lte: ["$$this.total1", "$$this.total2"] }
                    ]
                  },
                  { total2: { $add: ["$$this.total2", 1] } },
                  "$$this"
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }]
)
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/OtJ1WHRfkCT)